# Check File exist in Folder using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to check a file exist in folder. Below code is while i'm trying to many times is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Start()
{
var path = "X:\ApplicationFiles\Journals\TandF\RJHR\Vol00000\180008\ML\IProof\TF-RJHR180008.xml";
if (File.Exists(path))
{
document.getElementById("Stage").innerHTML = "exists";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr><th>Job ID</th><th>JID</th><th>Article ID</th><th>Intrnl ID</th><th>Due Date</th><th>Current Status</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>T76825</td><td>RJHR</td><td>1445583</td><td>180008</td><td>01-Mar-18</td><td><p id="Stage"/></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Who is upvoting this question?

Comment: Put some more effort in it sunshine!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

This wont work because your browser does not have access to your file system.

you can run this from a node.js server

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

Comment: Sir, Can you please tell me how to check the file exist in folder using this node.js server.

Comment: var fs = require('fs');
if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
    // Do something
}

Comment: you will need to create a myScript.js file and then run it as:node myScript.js

Comment: Sir, please provide full html code for this example. Please Sir! Please Sir! Please Sir! Please Sir!

Comment: its not HTML. you cannot check it using HTML. you need to use a server side language like node. please google node.js and "read file using node.js"

Answer (score 1):

You can't access local files in modern web browsers. There is the [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), but that involves direct user actions, you can't just use whatever files you please.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you cant access files using your browser , JavaScript is a view language its interact only with the browser, to be able to access local file you need to use a back end platform such as NodeJs or Php

Answer (score 0):

As I learned years ago you cannot access local file system with JS from browser, but things change. You can find more info here:

[Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

The article directs you to MDN but the solution works only in certain browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API

Comment: That API creates a virtual file system that lets the web app read and write its own files there. It still can't access aribtrary files on the user's computer.